# leanback player doesn't play items from playlist

Tags: html, audio, playlist, xspf

I have implemented the leanback player on my website. Now I'm trying to extend leanbackplayer with a XML (XPSF) playlist. The list is showing, but the songs don't play when clicked in the list.

I've set up a test page for the playlist: http://www.radiomerlijn.nl/mediaplayer/test_mediaplayer.htm

The songs do play when I press start on the player first, and then click a song in the playlist.

This is the code which I used for the leanbackplayer and playlist:

```
<div class="leanback-player-audio h5_lb_player" id="boekenplayer_parent" style="height: 0px;" width="auto">
<!-- HTML5 <audio> element -->  
<audio class="h5_lb_audio" id="boekenplayer" preload="metadata" tabindex="0">
<source src="http:www.rmuitzendinggemist.nl/uitzendinggemist/boekenxx03.mp3" type='audio/mpeg; codecs="vorbis"'/></audio>
  <div id="boekenplayer_list">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  // do: define XSPF Audio Playlist options
  LBP.XSPFAudio.options = {
    // if playlist style "width" is defined within your CSS; default is "false"
    fixedWidth: true
  };
  // do: provide XSPF Audio Playlist URL for HTML5 <audio> element id="unique_id"
  LBP.XSPFAudio["boekenplayer"] = "http://www.radiomerlijn.nl/rss/boekennieuws.xml";
</script>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Sander